# Using Qt with Visual Studio Code (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code

The following are installed:

- Visual Studio Code (1.45.1)
- Visual Studio 2019 Community (in order to use the MSVC `cl.exe` compiler)
- Qt 5.15.0 (installed to C:\Qt)

Visual Studio Code has been launched after running `Visual Studio Command Prompt` so that the environment is set correctly for `cl.exe`. The `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension has been installed in Visual Studio Code and `includePath` is set to:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "${INCLUDE}",
    "C:/Qt/5.15.0/msvc2019_64/include/**"
],
```

This file `hw.cpp`compiles and runs fine:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

The command used in `tasks.json` is:

```
"command": "cl.exe",
"args": [
    "/Zi",
    "/EHsc",
    "/Fe:",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "${file}"
],
```

Alternatively, from the in-built Terminal inside Visual Studio Code, the command "cl /EHsc /MD /O2 hw.cpp /link /out:hw.exe" compiles everything correctly and `hw.exe` can be executed.

But when I attempt to use Qt as follows it fails to compile:

```
#include <QString>
int main()
{
    QString test("Hello world!");
    qDebug() << test;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler reports "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QString': No such file or directory". IntelliSense does find QString.h, which opens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click `QString` (at the top).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to comments from @rioV8, I've investigated `/link` options for `cl.exe`. The task arguments have been updated to:

```
"args": [
    "/EHsc",
    "/MD",
    "/O2",
    "/IC:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include",
    "/IC:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include\\QtCore",
    "${file}",
    "/link",
    "/LIBPATH:C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\lib",
    "Qt5Core.lib",
    "qtmain.lib",
    "/OUT:${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
],
```

This has improved things slightly. `hw.cpp` now compiles and generates `hw.obj`, but now I get linker errors (one for each `.lib`):

```
warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
```

This is followed by `fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals`.

Getting closer, but still not linking.

Comment: add the paths to the compile line, you have added them to the intellisence search path, not the compiler search path. if you have multiple cpp files use a build tool like `make` or `CMake` or `qmake`

Comment: @rioV8: Thanks. I looked into the command-line options for `cl.exe`, and was not able to get them to work. I tried adding: "/experimental:external", "/external:I C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include", "/external:I C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include\\QtCore", "/external:W0", but I still get the same error. Did you know the correct syntax to add to the compiler search path?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019

Comment: @rioV8: OK, thanks. I managed to improve the syntax, so that `QString.h` is found. Requires: "/IC:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include", "/IC:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\msvc2019_64\\include\\QtCore". But the next problem is that the I need to link to the Qt library and now there are many `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` errors. Will add these details to the question.

Comment: Just look in the options about specifying library directories and libraries needed. Possible `/L`