# Can't Include Qt's Include Files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I want to learn Qt in C++ (using VSCode), but I can't because of this single problem.
I have tried:

1. Putting the include folder in c_cpp_properties (C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include)
2. Putting `INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include` in the project file (`.pro`)
3. Using /i compiler flag

If I run the file in VSCode (through `code .` from the developer command prompt for VS 2022), the error is:

```
C:\Users\<Name>\Pins\Codes\C++\testing.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: QtWidgets: no include path set
```

But if I run the file in the developer command prompt for VS 2022 (the compiler is in there), the error is:

```
testing.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWidgets': No such file or directory
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main() {
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(640, 480);
    window.show();
}
```

Comment: To use Qt in Visual Studio code see this question on Stack Overflow
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467456/using-qt-with-visual-studio-code-windows)

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I tried `cl /IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/ /IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtWidgets /std:<c++17> testing.cpp` and I got `The system cannot find the file specified.`. I made sure my file name is the same.

Comment: @MarcoBeninca Turns out `/std:<c++17>` was causing the system cannot find the file specified. But if I remove that, I will get another error saying Qt needs C++17. I did change the cppStandard value to c++17 in c_cpp_properties.json

Comment: Qt 6 ca be only used with C++17... I had a look on the folders of Qt and I saw that the file `QtWidgets` is inside `...../include/QtWidgets` so you miss the folder maybe in the include path

Comment: I did use that too. Right now the problem is when I use `/std:<c++17>` flag, it gives me `The system cannot find the file specified`; but if I don't use that flag, I get an error saying that it needs C++17. And if I remove the <>, I get the same error telling it needs C++17.

Comment: Did you tried `#include <QtWidgets\QtWidgets>`?

Comment: I can't, it just won't work. Look at my last comment.

Comment: One of the features of Visual Studio is the include path, which allows you to set a relative path for the includes. Does VS Code support this? The compatibility between VS Dev Cmd Prompt and VS Code may be the issue.

Comment: I'll try to use Visual Studio.

Comment: I've made a project, set the C++ to C++17, and added Qt's include path both in Include Directories and External Include Directories. When I try to run the file, I get `Unable to start program <path to exe file> The system cannot find the file specified`. Isn't it supposed to create the exe file first?

Answer (score 0):

Check include folder. I guess "QTWidgets" library can be found in its own folder or "Lib" folder, not in "include" folder.